# Writing a string to a text file - C#

Tags: c#, windows-embedded-compact

I'm trying to write a ip and port to a text file from user input. However the code below only saves part of the created string.

The code I use to write:

```
private void Edit_Config(string data)
{
    if (File.Exists(file_loc))
    {
        using (StreamWriter edFile = new StreamWriter(file_loc, false))
        {
            edFile.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //File not found, creates new config with new data.
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(file_loc))
        {
            Byte[] bytes = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(data);
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

The code I use to call the command

```
Edit_Config(txt_serverIP.Text + ":" + txt_port.Text);
```

What I get in return for example if I put '192.168.2.60:8080' I get '192.168.2.6' saved.

```
                edFile.Close();
```

Closing the file fixed the issue.

Comment: Put a Messagebox in the function to display the data string at the start of the routine. The error may be in the calling routine, not here.

Comment: Message box returns the correct output I should be getting into the file.

Comment: Does it fail both with a new file and adding to an existing file?

Comment: The new file also writes in the same fashion of '192.168.2.6', skipping the '0:8080'.

Comment: I was expecting the new file to be the bit which did it but wondered if it adds it incorrectly to an existing file too.

Comment: Shouldn't you close the file after you've written to it to make sure everything is written?

Comment: Closing seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 2):

As long as your `data` string is correct, this should handle everything you're doing in that method right now:

```
private void Edit_Config(string data)
{
    File.AppendAllText(file_loc, data);
}
```

---

This [should work in embedded framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.105).aspx):

```
private void Edit_Config(string data)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file_loc, true))
    {
       writer.WriteLine(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: AppendAllText doesn't work in the embedded framework sadly

Comment: Still gives the same result, oddly.